# Form not showing input data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a running form and it's half working. The form sends to my email address correctly but i'm having issues with the inputs not showing the text in the email. The only one that spits out any data is the message section.

The name, email, phone and website inputs are not spitting out any data and I can't figure out why?

// html5 code

```
   <form action="forms/get_form.php" method="post">
       <div>
         <label for="name">Name</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter name" required="required">
       </div>
       <div>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email address" required="required">
       </div>
       <div>
          <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="enter phone number" required="required">
        </div>
        <div>
           <label for="website">Enter website URL if you have one (optional)</label>
             <input type="url" id="website" placeholder="website address">
         </div>
         <div>
           <label for="message">Enter your message</label>
             <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn-blue">Send</button>
         </div>
  </form>
```

// php code

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Website: $website \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "email goes here";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
if(mail) {
header('Location: /thankyou.html'); 
} else {echo "Email failed to send click back and check email details!";}

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Vizzy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not ID but NAME param,

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter name" required="required">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name" required="required">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **ID**, use **name**.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name" required="required">
```